# Advice on resizing 1280*720 for web audiences

Tags: video, editing, recording, streaming, encoding

Forgive my spelling, I'm posting this from my mobile.

I've recently decided to record videos to help teach a visual language. My camera likes to boast it can record in 1280; its a cheap camera about £75 so the quality isn't amazing. But its okay.

Anyways, it has some other settings for lower res, but I figure might as well record in a larger size in case the need arises for a bigger source file in the future.

I've been looking at jw player to play the converted files (mp4 to flv I think). What do you think a good size would be to convert to? I want to to look nice and clear remembering it is a visual language so lip patterns, facial expressions, body movement, fingers etc are all important, sound is not that important but I would like to have a choice to toggle captions.

Thanks for any help,
any advice apreciated, first time I have done a video project!
P.s. If anyones interested its BSL.
Jamie

Comment: I agree that you should record in the highest resolution/quality that you can, and resize/reduce quality from there. As an aside, I'm surprised the camera doesn't boast something like 'records in 720 *HD*'

Answer (score 1):

You should just do a few different conversions of your source material at different resolutions and different bitrates. Higher quality is always nice, but it puts more load on your server and higher bandwidth requirements on your viewers.

Answer (score 1):

The standard resolution for video on the web is 320x240. YouTube or YouTube-like videos use a non-standard 450x338 resolution. I recommend the H.264 codec due to it high quality/low data rate.

As for a player, I recommend: [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) it combines jquery and flash.